# Hibernate Constraint Fail

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two object types: message and template. First I create a template, save it, then create a message, set message.template = template and then commit.

But -sometimes- I get an constraint fail exception, saying "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" - foreign key of message object which references template object.

Does Hİbernate have a commit order? Maybe trying to save message object first and -boom- template object is not committed yet. I don't have any other explanation of this error because this code works usually fine but sometimes error happens.

edit: 
This occurs in a large block of code i just cannot copy-paste it sorry.

Pseudo code summary:
Template template = new Template();
template.setTemplateName... etc
...etc

My DAO class saves template object. Not committing, saved in session.

Then similar scenary happens for message object, created, foreign keys, attributes are set and then saved. There happens the constraint fail.

I even tried to get that template object before i create and save message object to see if it exists (Template badTemplate = -my DAO class for template object . getByID() ), i can system.out "this template object's id is " + badTemplate.getTemplateId() + " and name is " + badTemplate.getTemplateName()" without any problem, but this does not prevent the fail. This code is used in an web service, i can get a successful return and my friend on another computer gets error.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: You should make shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem and post it.

Comment: I am using similar DAO classes and same database layer for many of my projects and none of them throws that exception. And even in this project constraint fail rarely happens -not always-, Reproducing the problem is not that easy.